# Qt Installer кириллица в пути

Tags: qt

Сделал инсталятор с Qt Installer, вроде бы всё нормально, но в пути для каталога установки, если попадается кириллица - выводится ошибка. Для меня понятна, а пользователей ввергает в иррациональный ужас и панику, так как пишет, что мол найден символ не относящийся к ANCII, выберите другую папку. Нельзя ли убрать это ограничение или хотя бы изменить текст этой ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простите дурака, не заметил сразу в документации. В одном из примеров сейчас наткнулся на такую строчку в конфиге.

```
<AllowNonAsciiCharacters>true</AllowNonAsciiCharacters>
```

Comment: А какую именно строчку?

Comment: Ох блин, воспринялось как теги. Исправил. @gil9red